# Controller is redirecting from one view to another on refreshing same url in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have create_student view which simply takes student name and generate auto increment primary key id, user_info session is saved after the user login, 
If there is validation error create_student view is rendered otherwise the recently inserted id of the student is returned from the student_model and 
the view for the student detail is opened i.e. student_detail view.

The issue is when i refresh this url `http://localhost/MyProject/create_student/Create_Student`
i go to the first view i.e. create_student from student_detail view and every time i reload this url when i am on student_detail view duplicate student entry
is being saved in database every time. Please help to solve my issue.

> create_student Controller:

```
public function Create_Student() {


   $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_title', 'Create Student', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

   $course_name=$this->input->post('title_title');  
   $user_info=$this->session->userdata('user_info');
   $user_id=$user_info['id'];

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
   {
    $this->load->view('create_student');
   }
   else
   {

    $data=array('u_id'=>$user_id,'course_title'=>$course_name);
    $result_student = $this->student_model->Create_Student($data);

    if($result_course!=false)
    {
        $data['result'] = $result_student;
        $this->load->view('student_detail',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('create_student');

    }
   }

}
```

> create_student View:

```
    <?php echo form_

open('create_student/Create_Student') ?>
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
  <input type="text" class="middle" name="student_title" class="middle"/>
  <button class="middle green" name="submit" type="submit">Create Student</button>
<?php echo form_close();  ?>
```

> Student_Model :

```
public function Create_Student($data) {

   $this->load->database();
   $this->db->insert('user', $data);
   $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
   if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
   return $insert_id;
   }
   else
   {
   return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: what is $result_course variable ?

Comment: Why don't you instead create a new controller affected to the display of a user detail and redirect to this page when the user is properly inserted in the database ? :)

Comment: @Adrian : I'm new to codeigniter can u please edit my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this coding in Controller

```
<?php create_student Controller:
public function Create_Student() {


   $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_title', 'Create Student', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

   $course_name=$this->input->post('title_title');  
   $user_info=$this->session->userdata('user_info');
   $user_id=$user_info['id'];

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
   {
    $this->student();
   }
   else
   {

    $data=array('u_id'=>$user_id,'course_title'=>$course_name);
    $result_student = $this->student_model->Create_Student($data);

    if($result_student)
    {
        redirect('create_student/student_details/'.$result_student);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->student();
    }
   }

 public function student_details() {
         $data['result'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->view('student_detail',$data);
 }

 public function student() {
      $this->load->view('create_student');
 }

}
?>
```

URL

`http://localhost/MyProject/create_student/student`

Comment: Thanks Vaira Muthu, but calling same controller method create disturbance in design, i.e. student()

Comment: I think this `<?php create_student Controller:` should be `<?php class Create_student extends CI_Controller {}`